# approach for validated form controls in AngularJS

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

My teammates and I are learning AngularJS, and are currently trying to do some simple form field validation. We realize there are many ways to do this, and we have tried

1. putting input through validation filters
2. using a combination of controller and validating service/factory
3. a validation directive on the input element
4. a directive comprising the label, input and error output elements

To me, the directive approach seems the most "correct". With #3, we ran into the issue of having to communicate the validation result to the error element (a `span` sibling). It's simple enough to do some scope juggling, but it seemed "more correct" to put the `span` in the directive, too, and bundle the whole form control. We ran into a couple of issue, and I would like the StackOverflow community's input on our solution and/or to clarify any misunderstandings.

```
var PATTERN_NAME = /^[- A-Za-z]{1,30}$/;

module.directive("inputName", [
  function () {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      require: "ngModel",
      scope: {
        fieldName: "@",
        modelName: "=",
        labelName: "@",
        focus: "@"      
      },
      template: '<div>' +
        '<label for="{{fieldName}}">{{labelName}}</label>' +
        '<input type="text" ng-model="modelName" id="{{fieldName}}" name="{{fieldName}}" placeholder="{{labelName}}" x-blur="validateName()" ng-change="validateName()" required>' +
        '<span class="inputError" ng-show="errorCode">{{ errorCode | errorMsgFltr }}</span>' +
        '</div>',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel)
      {
        var errorCode = "";

        if (scope.focus == 'yes') {
          // set focus
        }

        scope.validateName = function () {
          if (scope.modelName == undefined || scope.modelName == "" || scope.modelName == null) {
            scope.errorCode = 10000;          
            ngModel.$setValidity("name", false);
          } else if (! PATTERN_NAME.test(scope.modelName)) {
            scope.errorCode = 10001;            
            ngModel.$setValidity("name", false);
          } else {
            scope.errorCode = "";
            ngModel.$setValidity("name", true);
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

used as

```
<form novalidate name="addUser">
  <x-input-name
    label-name="First Name" 
    field-name="firstName" 
    ng-model="firstName"
    focus="yes"
    model-name="user.firstName">
  </x-input-name>

  <x-input-name 
    label-name="Last Name" 
    field-name="lastName" 
    ng-model="lastName"
    model-name="user.lastName">
  </x-input-name>
  ...
</form>
```

First, because both `form` and `input` are overridden by AngularJS directives, we needed access to the ngModel API (`ngModelController`) to allow the now-nested `input` to be able to communicate validity to the parent `FormController`. Thus, we had to `require: "ngModel"`, which becomes the `ngModel` option to the `link` function.

Secondly, even though `fieldName` and `ngModel` are given the same value, we had to use them separately. The one-way-bound (1WB) `fieldName` is used as an attribute value. We found that we couldn't use the curly braces in an `ngModel` directive. Further, we couldn't use a 1WB input with `ngModel` *and* we couldn't use a two-way-bound (2WB) input with values that should be static. If we use a single, 2WB input, the model works, but attributes like `id` and `name` become the values given to the form control.

Finally, because we are sometimes reusing the directive in the same form (e.g., first name and last name), we had to make attributes like `focus` parameters to be passed in.

Personally, I would also like to see the `onblur` and `onchange` events bound using JavaScript in the `link` function, but I'm not sure how to access the template markup from within `link`, especially outside/ignorant of the larger DOM.

Comment: Take a look at this excellent [blog](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation) that shows how form validations can be carried out using AngularJS.